# Debugging AngularJS with jetty

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

I'm not use to program with java (maven, jetty and IntelliJ). But I'm stuck on a problem which is make an `angularJS` app debug works.

When I execute de "package" phase of maven, I get an `.war` file and put it at webapps tomcat8 folder, it works perfectly. But when I try to debug it on the `IntelliJ with Jetty`, I get an `500 Http error` with a `null pointer exception` when the browser tries to get two files: the `app.js` and the `app.css`. Is there some config on jetty to make a angularJS app work?

EDIT:

The null pointer exception is because the java app tries to get the app.js and app.css files from the context path, and they do not exist in there. The maven build process creates another folder and put the build files result over there.

Comment: could you add the stack trace? A missing file usually generates just a 404 and not a NPE

Comment: actually the problem is that the maven minify plugin put the compiled minified files on a target folder so thiese files exists but they are on the compiled folder